# How could I improve the accuracy of pytesseracts image to text function?

Tags: python, pyautogui, python-tesseract

I'm trying to make a python bot for a steam game called typing incremental.

Using pyautogui and pytesseract the code takes a screenshot of the region of the game the text appears, then converts it to a string, that is then typed by pyautogui.

The issue is that pytesseracts conversion of the image to a string is highly inaccurate, only being able to accurately convert single letter words (A), and nothing else.

I've tried most of the things I can thing of but I'm still very new to programming so it is very likely that I have missed something that will be obvious to you but difficult for me.

I've tried, adding a delay to the code, changing the region the code screenshots numerous times and adding a whitelist to the words it can detect (although I'm not entirely sure if this actually worked)

Edit: Apologies I forgot to include the actual code I was using, sorry about that

```py
import pytesseract 
import pyautogui
import time
import keyboard
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = "C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR//tesseract.exe"

time.sleep(1)

while True: 
    if keyboard.is_pressed("`"):
        break 
    
    image = pyautogui.screenshot(region=(285, 155, 1566, 210))
    time.sleep(1)
    converted = pytesseract.image_to_string(image)
```

Comment: are the screenshots of the game super low quality? i would recommend taking a screenshot and saving it and then trying to get pytesseract to ID the text in isolation, outside of the bigger script and all that

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: are the screenshots of the game super low quality? i would recommend taking a screenshot and saving it and then trying to get pytesseract to ID the text in isolation, outside of the bigger script and all that – ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
I'm not entirely sure where pyautogui saves its screenshots so how would I go about doing that?

As far as the game itself is concerned its very high quality, definitely high enough that I can't see it causing any issues with the bot.

Comment: Can you share a example screenshot and what is your result?